# mkdir(): Permission denied Permissions is set

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

I know there is a lot of answers for this already but it just doesn't work.

I am trying to make my php script to create a folder on my ubuntu apache server.

```
if (!@mkdir($url, 0700, true)) {
    $error = error_get_last();
    echo $error['message'];
}
```

Now I have changed the permission for `www-data` to `777` and `www-data` owns the folder `var/www/html` and all of the subdirectories.

Now what to do?

The `$url` I pass is `/files/test3`

I have tested with `/files/test3/` as well but that doesn't work.

Edit:

This is how my files are sorted atm using `tree`
[image: This is how my files are sorted atm using tree]

Comment: I see you use the STFU operator (@), do you receive any errors without it? If so, please provide it.

Comment: What happends if you try this: 


`$old = umask(0);`
`mkdir($url, 0700, true);`
`umask($old);`

Comment: Tried the unmask and that did nothing. However when I removed @ it worked but it created a folder in the same folder as that file (includes) not where I wanted it to be (files)

Comment: You should check who is executing your script and then see if the permission and groups are set correctly. Do some debuging and just go step by step and see the dump/log for it

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to make a folder with an absolute path (/files/test3) which literally makes /files/test3 [which you probably do not own /files, and cannot make folders off / because you're not root], not /var/www/html/files/test3.

You can use `__DIR__ . '/' . $url` or set $url to `files/test3` instead.

Comment: Thanks! I thought that were the problem aswell but I have checked the permission for that folder aswell and I have read and write permissions for that folder aswell. The `__DIR__ .'/'. $url` or `files/test3` did'nt work either unfortunatelly

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$url = '~/files/test3/';

if (!mkdir($url, 0700, true)) {
    $error = error_get_last();
    echo $error['message'];
}
```

Should create a folder `files`, with another folder `test3` inside of it, in the home directory.

Comment: but `www-data` has no home directory.